# From which version does Safari not support 32 bit architecture?

Tags: macos, safari, web-browser, 32-bit

I have a problem with Safari on different macOS versions. Is there any information from which version Safari doesn't support 32 bit architecture? Like Firefox (from v.56) and Chrome (from v.74) on macOS.

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: Yes, tell us what the problem is, because it probably isn't whether Safari is 32-bit or not. Also, the question doesn't really make sense: the *OS* supports or doesn't support 32-bit architecture; Safari is or isn't compiled as 32-bit or 64-bit binary code.  Safari doesn't 'support' architectures.

Comment: I'm going to guess the asker has a 32bit NPAPI plugin they need to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)#64-bit_builds - Safari has been 64-bit since Snow Leopard OS X 10.6 in 2009, which would be Safari 5, [around the same time they stopped supporting Windows.]

All Macs since then have been 64-bit capable, but until Catalina have been backwards compatible with 32-bit applications.
The last OS X to be capable of running on 32-bit architecture was also Snow Leopard, 10.6

The App Store will only offer you builds of Safari compatible with your Mac's hardware & OS
Safari 11 - 10.11 to 10.12
Safari 12 - 10.12 to 10.13
Safari 13 - 10.13 to 10.15
Safari 14 - macOS 11 [backwards compatibility currently unknown]